# Google Cloud KMS error - This API is not acessible from your region. (HTTP status - 403)

Tags: google-cloud-kms

I have created a google cloud project and enabled **Google Cloud Key Management Service (KMS) API**. I have created two keyrings. `keyring1` is located in `us-east1` and `keyring2` is located in `global`. I have created the following java program to list the keyrings in the region:

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
credential = credential.createScoped(CloudKMSScopes.all());

String keyRingPath = "projects/<<projectId>>/locations/global";

CloudKMS kms = new CloudKMS.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("CloudKMS snippets").build();

ListKeyRingsResponse response = kms.projects().locations().keyRings().list(keyRingPath).execute();

System.out.println(response.getKeyRings());
```

I am getting following **forbidden** error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "This API is not acessible from your region.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "This API is not acessible from your region.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to invoke the Cloud KMS APIs from India. Looks like Cloud KMS is not yet available in all the locations. Cloud KMS service is not yet available in India. Click [here](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/restrictions) to know the list of countries where Cloud KMS is available. That is why I was getting the `This API is not acessible from your region.` error

Answer (score 4):

I'm an engineer working on Cloud KMS.

Unfortunately, there are many complexities in making this service available in individual countries and we don't have a specific timeline as to when or if any particular country will be rolled out.

Anyone who is interested in the availability of a particular country should contact us to see if any information is available and to help us prioritize.

Comment: As of [Aug 18th](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/release-notes#august_18_2017), there is a longer list of available countries for Cloud KMS.